# Intermittent WiFi connection

Tags: wireless-networking

Every morning, after I've turned on my laptop (Windows 10 Pro), I have the same problem: the WiFi connection is going on and off in an erratic pattern - sometimes as fast as a few times per minute. During the next hours, the connection becomes gradually more stable until this problem is gone.

It's a new laptop (aug '17), the problem is from the last weeks. If I look at my network adapters (Control Panel, Network and Internet, Network Connections), I can see the status of my WiFi adapter changing from "Not connected" to "Identifying ..." to the name of my local domain to "Not connected" to ... etc.

I'm a few meters away from the AP, a Fritz!WLAN Repeater 1750E and my router is a Fritz!Box 7360. Normally, I see a wireless speed of around 850 to 900 Mbps. It seems no other devices on my network have this problem, so for now I'm ruling out any problem in my local domain. Also, at least for now, I'm ruling out any hardware problem.

Basically I've tried two things: look into my network card/drivers and look into installed software.

I have a MSI GS73VR 7RG Stealth Pro with a Killer network card. There are problems reported with that, so I've uninstalled the Killer Networking software and reinstalled only the (most recent) drivers. No difference.

I don't see any peculiar things in the programs I've installed. Most of them I've been using for many years. But there is a whole lot going on after starting up and it's difficult to trace. I've uninstalled several programs that I'm less familiar with, to no avail.

Now I'm stuck and my network knowledge is just to basic. How do I find out *why* my WiFi connection is interrupted? Is there any software (or other solution) around that makes it easier to solve this problem?

Comment: (A) Look to your WAP; if it's old, you may be seeing it start to die; (B) get one of those apps that can show you wifi signal info, including both strength and channel; you may have other signals nearby that are stepping on you.

Comment: The WAP is new (2017) but I didn't try a WiFi analyzer yet. I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot this question was still open, so here is a delayed solution.

Which was to disable the radio network on the router. The router provides 2.4 GHz only, the repeaters provide 5 GHz also. I suspect there was some interference and/or signal strength variations which led to the drop-outs.